# Include operator overloads from another file

Tags: c++, header, operator-overloading

I want to use an operator defined in another file and if possible, another namespace as well, here is what I have.

(operators.hpp)

```
#ifndef __OPERATORS__HPP__
#define __OPERATORS__HPP__

#include "proto_handler.hpp"

#include <iostream>

namespace apius {
namespace support {
namespace operators{

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in,
                         inventory::proto::item& item);
}
}
}
```

(operatos.cpp)

```
#include "operators.hpp"

namespace apius {
namespace support {
namespace operators{

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in,
                         inventory::proto::item& item){
    //code here
}

}
}
}
```

(another_file.cpp)

```
#include "operators.hpp"

extern std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in,
                         inventory::proto::item& item);
void test(){
    inventory::proto::item new_item;
    std::cin>>new_item;
}
```

and I get undefined reference to operator at line containing std::cin

What can I do to make this work?

Comment: Why do you declare an `operator>>` in a `another_file.cpp` when there is one in `operators.hpp` ?

Comment: Instead of the erroneous re-declaration mentioned, you should have something like `using namespace apius::support::operators;` to expose the previous declaration of your `<<` operator.

Comment: Okay, this was a dumb mistake on my part, thank you both for resolving it so quickly!

Comment: Note that if you had declared the operator in `inventory::proto::item`, no `using` would have been needed because the operator would have been found by Koenig's lookup.  This is usually the preferred method to find operators.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but name that contain two consecutive underscores (`__OPERATORS__HPP__`) and names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved for use by the implementation. Don't define them in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically the linker is struggling to find such symbol because there is no one. Because of the C++ name mangling you'll get something like **__ZN5apius7support9operatorsrsERNSt3__113basic_istream...** in your symbol table in an object file. Notice that the namespace part is also there. But you're telling that there is such operator in a global namespace. As Adrian correctly noticed you can simply add

```
using namespace apius::support::operators;
```

Furthermore, what I prefer to do it is to declare a friend operator in a class and then you don't need any usings.